# How do I differentiate between commonly named methods shared by two components of my class?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I have a class structure that looks something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Origin
{
public:
    void SetOrigin(T x, T y) { __x = x; __y = y; }
    void SetOrigin(vector2<T> vect) { __x = vect.x; __y = vect.y; }

private:
    T __x;
    T __y;
}
class Sprite : Origin<float>
{
public:
    using Origin::SetOrigin;
}
class Text : Origin<int>
{
public:
    using Origin::SetOrigin;
}
class Button : Sprite, Text
{
public:
    using Sprite::SetOrigin;
    using Text::SetOrigin;
}
```

The class `Button` should have 2 different origins, the origin of the `Text` (where is the text in the `Button`) and the origin of the `Button` itself.

I don't want to have to cast the argument to `float` or `int`, because it should be obvious what method is called, so I'd like to call the second one `btn.SetTextOrigin(x, y)`.

In this very simple case, I can just reimplement the methods with different names, but I have to make as many implementations as there are overloads of `SetOrigin` in class `Sprite`.

Is there an easier way to use all `SetOrigin` methods with a different name than to reimplement all of them? (Implementing 20 functions just to have a different name is pretty boring.)

For example, is it possible to change the name of a method in the derived class without rewriting each overloaded function? I think of something like:

```
using Text::SetOrigin as SetTextOrigin;
```

or

```
using SetTextOrigin = Text::SetOrigin
```

But I haven't found anything, if there is nothing like that, what would you suggest doing in that case?

Comment: It feels sprite and text are parts of your button ... so should be members, not base classes.

Comment: As @ÖöTiib says, be sure your `Button` class _isA_ `Text` and _isA_ `Sprite` when inheriting from both (I'd suspect it isn't). You're asking for a XY-problem, and your design is flawed.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Notice there's private inheritance used. That's not `is-a`, that's `implemented-in-terms-of-a`.

Comment: hm... well, it feels like you're right @ÖöTiib, thanks!

But is it possible to just Rename the Function in the derived class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks to me that the button is better implemented as containing Sprite and Text.  It won't save you anything on typing, in fact, you'll likely write a little bit more code, but it be a cleaner design.  The button is neither a sprite or text - it can have a sprite and a text.  So making the sprite and text member variables would be a lot more straightforward way of expressing the nature of their relationship.

Also, should the button have an origin different from either the sprite or text, e.g. say, the location of button's corner?

Are all buttons on the system expected to have both the text and the image?
Is it possible to add other elements to the button with the origin.  I don't know, maybe two text elements with different fonts?

In this case, you may end up aggregating the origin elements.

Comment: That's not actually an answer to the question. And whether it contains by base-subobject or member-subobject seems unimportant here.

Comment: Well, It's an anwer to my Problem, not to the question.

I'll still appoint it as accepted because I'll have to rework something and doing something like using the same method as in the base but with a different name is probably not really usefull in general

Comment: I agree, @Deduplicator. This is the accepted answer, but it only really addressed the *example* that motivated the question, rather than answering the question head-on. I've therefore edited the question a little to make this answer fit better.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can  call the functions like this

```
button myButton;
myButton.text::setOrigin();
myButton.sprite::setOrigin();
```

Comment: Nope, i inherit private.
And i want to call the Method with a different name to make it obvious which one is used. (just casting the arguments would probably work too)

Comment: _"I believe ..."_ doesn't make this a really trustworthy answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement two different named methods:

```
class Button : public Sprite, public Text
{
  public:
    void SetSpriteOrigin()
    {
      Sprite::SetOrigin();
    }
    void SetTextOrigin()
    {
      Text::SetOrigin();
    }
  private:
    void SetOrigin(); // Prevent users from using this ambiguous method.
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I'd have to reimplement them for each Method where i want to change the name, and since this method may be overloaded I'd have to implement a method for each different overload.